# Podman search only shows name and description column

Tags: linux, containers, podman, centos8

New to linux /Podman environment , how do i enable podman search command to show all columns, i am basically looking for the column that shows you stars for a particular image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaOTD.png)

I am basically looking for the query to show all columns. any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Post the text itself in your question, formatted as a code sample.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is easy, check `podman search --help`; you will find `--compatible`. For example:

```
podman search --compatible httpd
```